# can two overlapping buttons recieve the same click?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, button, overlap

I am new to flex and as3 and I need to create a workaround for a button issue. I don't know how to have one button created by one class send a click event to another item created in a different class

Therefore, I'd like to place both of my buttons on top of one another, alpha one of them out and have both buttons receive the same click.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One button's click handler can dispatch another button's click event. See this: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/createevents_3.html

Comment: And this .. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_07.html :)